# remove cron jobs along with their comment, environment which were created by Puppet by awk/sed

Tags: shell, awk, sed, cron, puppet

Is there a way to remove/delete cron jobs created by Puppet by using awk/sed? I know that we can edit by `crontab -e` command manually, but this is a question for scripting.
Example root cron is a file in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`. I want to remove lines below.

```
# Puppet Name: cron1
MAILTO=root@localhost.com,admin@localhost
* * * * * /bin/true
# Puppet Name: cron test
PATH="/usr/local/bin"
MAILTO=root@localhost.com
2-57 * * * * echo "test"
# Puppet Name: thank you
* * * * * echo "Thank you!"
....
```

Puppet cron has patterns:

1. Begin with `# Puppet Name:`
2. It can contain Cron Environment or not. This can be multiple lines

If anyone knows how to do it, please help.
Thank you!

Comment: *This can be multiple lines* Then how lines that are supposed to remain can be discerned from those that should be deleted?

Comment: Why not also use Puppet to remove the entries?

Comment: In  your example include lines that were NOT added by Puppet and so should presumably remain unaltered after the command you're asking for help to write executes.

Comment: Above example should be blank, those lines should be removed all. I'm on the way to migrate to Ansible so I can't use puppet now. Lines weren't added by puppet should be untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be well advised to use Puppet to remove the crontab entries that were created by Puppet.

If you have to do it via a manual-ish shell command, however, then you can do it via this `sed` command:

```
sed -nie '/^# Puppet Name:/!{p;d};:p;n;/^[ \t]*\(\|#.*\|[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*[ \t]*=.*\)$/ b p' \
  /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
```

**Explanation**

The command assumes that each group of lines to delete starts with a "Puppet Name:" comment and continues up to and including the next line that is neither blank (but for whitespace), nor a comment, nor an environment variable assignment.  It modifies the specified file in place (`-i`), with auto-printing disabled (`-n`).  The expression (`-e`) does the following:

- If the next line read does not start with the text "`# Puppet Name:`" then print that line and start the next cycle (`{p;d}`).  Otherwise,
- this point in the expression is labelled "p" (`:p`);
- silently (because auto-print is disabled) read the next line of input (`n`);
- if the current line is blank, is a comment, or is an environment setting then branch to label p (`b p`);
- else the end of the expression is reached. Silently (because auto-print is disabled) start the next cycle.

Comment: I have found that using puppet to remove the crontab entries is problematic because puppet does not know that the resource has been removed from the manifest and without the the original parameters you don't know what the cron resource was called.
What I want is `cron{"crontab*": ensure => absent}` to remove all puppet cron entries matching `crontab*`

Comment: @RussellFulton, that would be the subject of a different question.,